Getting Table Column Value Based on Dynamic Column Name
I have a 'column specifier' table that specifies the names of 1 or more columns of a source table that contain the data needed for stuff. The list of columns required depends on various things, but here, it depends only on what I'm calling the 'cid'. I must retrieve the values found in each column of the data table that is a column specified in the specifier, or column table, and do that for the one row of the data table where the cid matches that of column table rows. I have tried a few approaches, but the closest I've been is to create the dynamic SQL that retrieves one column at a time. The setup for this:
The specifier or column table is ColumnTable:
create table #ColumnTable (
    cid integer,
    columnName varchar(20),
    colValue integer);

insert into #ColumnTable (
    cid,
    columnName)
values
    (23, 'col1'),
    (23, 'col2'),
    (23, 'col3'),
    (34, 'col1'),
    (34, 'col3'),
    (43, 'col2'),
    (43, 'col1'),
    (43, 'col4'),
    (44, 'col2');

...and the source or data table is:
    create table #DataTable (
     cid  integer
   , col1 integer
   , col2 integer
   , col3 integer
   , col4 integer
   , col5 integer);

insert into #DataTable (
    cid
  , col1
  , col2
  , col3
  , col4
  , col5)
values
    (23, 1,   2,  3,  4, 37),
    (34, 7,  10, 13,  4, 3),
    (43, 5,   2,  4,  4, 35),
    (44, 19, 12, 13, 24, 53);

So, 'col1', 'col2' etc are the literal column names I'm told I need to get the row values from, for the row where 'cid' is as specified. There will be only one row per cid in the source data, potentially dozens of columns any one or more of which are my quarry. I can know the complete list of actual column names and their column sequence numbers for the data table, and I can get the same information from the specifier table. The final result is an updated colValue column of the column specifier table, which for this example is:
cid columnName  colValue
23  col1         1
23  col2         2
23  col3         3
34  col1         7
34  col3        13
43  col2         2
43  col1         5
43  col4         4
44  col2        12

I have used string_agg to aggregate the column names found in the specifier table, but I need to get those column values from the row of the data table where data.cid = column.cid, in part to ensure I can update the column table with the correct values. I have the added issue of the specifier's column names being in rows. Any guidance appreciated, even if it's a different way to think the problem.

It's not very clear, if you have this system in place already, shouldn't there already be a way to do this stuff? And if you're designing this now, why would you do that?

The end query should look something like: Update t set colvalue = case columnname when 'col1' then s.col1 when 'col2' then col2... END from #target t inner join #source s ON s.cid = t.cid so just generate that from your list of columns?

This is a very problematic table design. If you ask another question about what you're solving with this design, we might be able to help. There's probably a better way. For example, dataTable could be redesigned to be a key/value table or use a JSON column.

Not concerning table design.
To join a row of data with columns of data, you can use UNPIVOT.
See example
with upvt as(
  SELECT cid, colName, colValue
  FROM (
      SELECT cid, col1, col2, col3, col4, col5
      FROM #DataTable
    ) p
  UNPIVOT(
    colValue FOR colName IN (col1, col2, col3, col4, col5)
  ) AS unpvt
)
select c.cid,c.columnName,u.colValue 
from #ColumnTable c
left join upvt u on u.cid=c.cid and c.columnName=u.colName;




cid
columnName
colValue




23
col1
1


23
col2
2


23
col3
3


34
col1
7


34
col3
13


43
col2
2


43
col1
5


43
col4
4


44
col2
12



Main case is UNPIVOT #DataTable.  There unpivot part of above query and unpivot result.
  SELECT cid, colName, colValue
  FROM (
      SELECT cid, col1, col2, col3, col4, col5
      FROM #DataTable
    ) p
  UNPIVOT(
    colValue FOR colName IN (col1, col2, col3, col4, col5)
  ) AS unpvt




cid
colName
colValue




23
col1
1


23
col2
2


23
col3
3


23
col4
4


23
col5
37


34
col1
7


34
col2
10


34
col3
13


34
col4
4


34
col5
3


43
col1
5


43
col2
2


43
col3
4


43
col4
4


43
col5
35


44
col1
19


44
col2
12


44
col3
13


44
col4
24


44
col5
53



fiddle


Any guidance appreciated, even if it's a different way to think the problem.

Redesign dataTable to be a key/value table like so...
create table dataTable (
  cid integer not null,
  key varchar(255) not null,
  value int,
  primary key(cid, key);
);

insert into #DataTable(cid, key, value)
values
    (23, 'col1', 1),
    (23, 'col2', 2),
    (23, 'col3', 3),
    (23, 'col4', 4),
    (23, 'col5', 37);

Then join and select directly by key.
select dt.*
from ColumnTable ct 
left join DataTable dt
  on dt.cid = ct.cid 
 and dt.key = ct.ColumnName

This way you can have any keys you want, as many as you want.

If DataTable is already in use, you can create a view for backwards compatibility.

The design issue is that 'data table' is a UDF being used as a report--so it can't be changed. This 'report' product is of a fixed design, but a different set of its columns can be used as parameters to determine some other value. You can think of having a wide variety of functions f(x) = y, where the function f1 is f1(c1, c2), f2 is f2(c2, c3, c4) and so on. Which function is applied to the UDF dataset is selected by User. I have to be a bit cryptic about the actual use, but that's the explanation for the weird situation.

The comment by siggemannen above (the 2nd comment) actually solves the problem perfectly. The idea of a CASE statement did occur to me, but I dismissed it immediately without even sketching it out, thinking it would be somehow horrific to implement. Took about 10 minutes to implement and works very nicely. Thanks to everyone.
